# Copy Linux liveUSB causes errors with init.d scripts

Tags: java, linux, daemon, startup, init.d

---

**The Overall Problem**

---

When I install a simple Java application that I wrote to run on boot in the background through /etc/init.d/, it works on the liveUSB that I explicitly install it on. When I make a copy of that stick, it never boot successfully. When booting the liveUSB copy the Java application will always hang when the liveUSB boot process reaches my script. My script, which does do exactly what it is supposed to do, even every 5 minutes and will continue running forever until you power down the machine.

1. My script is blocking everything else
2. Nothing loads beyond my script
3. You cannot cancel my script
4. There is no GUI
5. The only text you can see is the command line output from my script

---

**Setup & Test** - Everything goes well :)

---

I have a Linux liveUSB with 3 partitions. Simple standard Xubuntu image is loaded.

- sda1 > 2gb stoage
- sda2 > 2gb system
- sda3 > remaining gb for casper

I have created a simple Java application that runs in the background on start up. To get this far, I followed these steps:

1. Compiled java application into classes
2. Placed class files in /home/user/folder/
3. Copied my startup.sh script into /etc/init.d/
4. While inside /etc/init.d/

   - Typed "update-rc.d startup.sh start 20 2 5 . stop 20 0 1 6 ."
   - This updated run levels successfully
5. Now I can restart / reboot / shutdown whatever operation and everything runs perfectly!

---

**The Copy** - Here's where it gets tricky!

---

When creating a copy of this stick, I follow these steps:

1. Mount sda2

   - copy everything from that folder to /home/user/Desktop/tmp-system/
2. Mount sda3

   - copy everything from that folder to /home/user/Desktop/tmp-casper/
3. Go into /home/user/Desktop/tmp-system/

   - Type "tar -cvf system.tar ."
4. Go into /home/user/Desktop/tmp-casper/

   - Type "tar -cvf casper.tar ."
5. Umount

   - sda2
   - sda3
6. Plug in empty USB (sdb for example)

   - Set up partitions (Same as the stick you are copying from)
   - Untar into partitions

     - tar -xvf system.tar ... into sdb2
     - tar -xvf casper.tar ... into sdb3

---

**Testing** - Here's where everything goes wrong!

---

1. Plug in newly created liveUSB into a computer
2. Boot from USB
3. Everything starts to boot fine
4. Java application that I wrote gets triggered

   - Boot process hangs forever
   - No cmd prompt available
   - NO GUI available
   - It is as if the thread is running (and it is! The output can be viewed every 5 minutes - which is exactly the way it should be)

---

**Solution Attempts & Gotchas**

---

**1**

I can mount the copied liveUSB edit the startup.sh to not start my Java application and it will still not boot (just as I suspected?).

---

**2**

If I use "dd if=sda of=sdb" the copy of the liveUSB will work perfectly fine. However this is not an acceptable solution. If I were to copy a 16gb stick with dd to a 64gb stick, that would turn the 64gb stick into a 16gb.

---

**3**

Tested many variations of startup.sh and the Java application itself. All of which produce the same error.

---

**4**

The method I am using to copy works for every other form of application, file or anything else.

---

**5**

I would also like to try and avoid using any additional libraries or programs to help run the Java application.

Comment: Very good problem definition. But... I don't see this as a programming problem. You're better to flag this and ask a moderator to move to Superuser.com. Good luck.

Comment: I have it posted there as well :S

Answer (score 0):

What you might better do is to use a method to quickly create a liveUSB Linux stick, then add the Java program settings and directories. 
Here is some help - [Bootable pendrive as live cd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529678/bootable-pendrive-as-live-cd/9534219#9534219)

I definitely like point number 1 that you mention. Copy liveUSB even without the Java program does not work. You have spent quite some time to debug that program. I have the feeling that you are interested in making many liveUSB with the Java program installed. Since dd is not an option, my guess is that it's more meaningful to somehow use a Kickstart procedure for quick LiveUSB installations and then copy the Java things. 
Thanks.